# Replace any number with a specific number from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have link like this foo.net/index.php?page=15

And I need to replace any number after page=*xxx* and get the new number from variable

This my current code just replace 15 to 16

```
var num = 16,

// What if the str = foo.net/index.php?page=10
    str = 'foo.net/index.php?page=15',
    n = str.replace('15',num);

$('span').html(n);
```

You can check the code in http://jsfiddle.net/KMsv7/

Comment: `var n = str.replace(/\d+/,num);` ?

Comment: A somewhat dirty solution could be `n = str.split('page=')[0] + 'page=' + num;`, but it works.

Comment: You want to replace the existing number with a number one greater? So 15 to 16, 92 to 93..?

Comment: @undefined that works, but please tell me what is `/\d+/` and how to use it?

Comment: @Jim, this is Regular expression - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @undefined waiting for your official answer to give you the reputation points.

Comment: That's nice of you, the point is not reputation points :), thanks.

Comment: @undefined Still will help people out to see the solution in approved answer with some piece of info about regular expression :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select and replace numbers in a string you can use regular expression:

```
// Replacing macting number with the specified value
var n = str.replace(/\d+/, num);
```

In case that you want to add/subtract/divide/multiply the matching value, you can also use the callback function of the `.replace()` method:

```
var n = str.replace(/\d+/, function(number) {
   return number + 1;
});
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: what if the page link has number like this **foo.net/index2.php?page=15**, is there a way to jume to the number after =

Comment: @Jim Yes, you can add `=` to the regex, `str.replace(/=\d+/, '=n');`